# User is not Authenticated after ExternalSignInAsync

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm using asp.net identity with facebook authentication.
After the redirection from facebook login page to ExternalLoginCallback action in the account controller (I use the standard VS template) I call the SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync, that returns a success result, but if check the User.Identity.IsAuthenticated property it's false.

Why?

Comment: When are you checking `IsAuthenticated`? If it's before the request has returned to the user that is by design.

Comment: yes...it's before the request has returned..I thought it was by designed..but I don't understand why..I would expect to have the User.Identity set after ExternalSignInAsync was called

Comment: Because an owin middleware component is reponsible for authentication, not your application. So it has to "feed back through" that pipeline in order to actually authenticate a user. All the "SignIn" methods do is signal the middleware piece to perform that action.